# Twitter etiquette for hashtag stream

Tags: twitter

When I participate in a hashtag stream on Twitter, is it best to start the tweets with the hashtag or end them with it?

Usually, if just making a regular tweet, I'll occasionally include a hashtag mid-tweet or at the end.

But, if it's a trending topic, for example '#nameacolour' and I know I'll be posting several tweets in succession i.e. several in a short space of time, should I go with "# blue","# green" or with "blue #","green #"? Hope that makes sense!

There's doesn't seem to be a set best way of doing this. I was against starting tweets with a hashtag but perhaps would be best as have followers for different reasons (tweet on lots of different things).

Comment: I really don't think it matters. All Twitter is doing when searching is showing all posts that contain the search term - in this case the hashtag - regardless of position in the Tweet.

Answer (score 2):

It does not really matter much, although it is best to put the hashtag at the end of the tweet, unless the hashtag is more commonly used as part of a sentence. Putting the hashtag at the end of the tweet is much neater (in my opinion) and does not affect normal reading when the second half of the tweet is cut off.